# ASP.NET Login page

Tags: asp.net

I want to add login for registered users in my website. How shall I proceed with it? Is it through the use of sessions? What will happen to the Session variable once the logout happens??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is extremely broad and there are many different ways that you can implement what is, in effect, a "membership" system for an ASP.NET website.

I would suggest that you start by reading the "[Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)" article from MSDN.  This article will give you an overview of how ASP.NET membership works in the most "standard" way.

It also mentions using the various ASP.NET membership "controls" ([Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx), [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx), [LoginStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.aspx) & [PasswordRecovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery.aspx) for example).

Using these controls along with the built-in ASP.NET membership providers (for example, ASP.NET provides a [SQL membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998317.aspx) to work against SQL Server as the data store for your user accounts and credentials) will allow you to implement a complete membership and authentication system with virtually no code at all (i.e. all the functionality is provided by the built-in "membership" controls and declarative mark-up).

Finally, a really good series of articles on this subject is:

[Examining ASP.NET 2.0's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)

from the 4guysfromrolla site.  It's starts at the very beginning of the membership topic and goes right the way through to touching on the implementation of a custom membership provider and administrative interface for managing user credentials to round out the whole subject.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look a related questions, such as

[Login Membership .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592364/login-membership-net)

This topic is already covered quite a lot on SO.

Session state and log in are somewhat orthogonal. You have a session regardless of whether or not you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the provided `Login` control and `Membership` system.

About Session vars, nothing special will happen. ASP.NET forms authentication does not use SessionState by default.

Comment: I dont want to use the Login Control.

Comment: Then you can use the underlying membership APIs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(loband).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using forms authentication with perhaps a custom backend using IIdentity and IPrincipal. There’s lots of information available how to do this but I think this link forms a good starting point http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx