# ASP.NET custom log-in

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I just started learning about ASP.NET, and I have a couple of questions.

Am I required to use the ASP.NET login control for a secure log in?
If not, can I do it the old-fashioned way, with calls to a MySQL DB?
If so, how do I keep track of which users are logged in, and how do I restrict access?

I've tried googling but everything is on the asp.net login control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Login page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755637/asp-net-login-page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's too many ways not to get this right - sure you can use your own UI controls for login, but you should not roll the backend / infrastructure for this on your own. Stick with the Membership authentication if you can, this should work well for you - there is no reason to re-invent the wheel if you do not have requirements that cannot be met by Membership authentication.

Also there is a Membership provider for MySQL you can use, i.e. see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx).

Comment: I agree 100% - only roll your own if the app requirements REQUIRE a feature that is not supported by the Framework implementation. Good answer!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading through Scott Mitchell's ["Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile"](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) series. This will definitely give you the information you need to implement your own login control and membership provider (using MySQL or any other data store you want).